# Styling of initial default value of a text field

Tags: html, css, input, fonts

I have a html input textfield as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="fName" class="inpField" size="20" value="First Name *" />
```

Now I want to do selective styling of some text as follows:

1. I have the default value set as "First Name *". Using css- I want to apply a global style to that whole thing- such as font-family, font-size.
2. Then I want to selectively style  the asterisk (*) after the First Name with color red. Since that * is a value contained in an attribute- how do I selectively select only the asterisk part in the value attribute to make it red.

Please help.

Comment: The simple answer is, no you can't.

Comment: haha, i just did it.

Comment: If you mean you used the accepted answer, then **no, you didn't**. That's just used another `span` element and positioned it over the top of the input.

Comment: only the end result matters, yes it's a workaround- but i did modify his example and used some jqyery too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to style *only* the `*`, you're out of luck. No way to do that in just CSS. There is, however, way of doing this with altering your DOM:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" name="fName" class="inpField" size="20" value="First Name" />
  <span class="input-addon">*</span>
</div>
```

Then, the CSS:

```
.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-addon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je97om6t/)

Comment: I have the default value set as "First Name *". Using css- I want to apply a global style to that whole thing- such as font-family, font-size.

Then I want to selectively style the asterisk (*) after the First Name with color red. Since that * is a value contained in an attribute- how do I selectively select only the asterisk part in the value attribute to make it red.

Answer (score 5):

You can target `input` with the specified value of the`value` attribute (if you want to target `value` *starting* with *"First Name"*, you can use `^=` instead of `=`):

```
input[type="text"][value="First Name"] {
   font-size: 10px;
   color: red;
   <...>
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrg2qvwc/)

Comment: Certainly correct, but what if the content in the VALUE for the field changes in the future? You'd have to update the value="" CSS rule accordingly to match. Perhaps safer to target a parent id / class and input[value]?

Comment: @samuidavid: well, `id` is more flexible of course, but the question is about targeting _specified_ `value`, so I'm sticking to the answer.

Comment: I have the default value set as "First Name *". Using css- I want to apply a global style to that whole thing- such as font-family, font-size.

Then I want to selectively style the asterisk (*) after the First Name with color red. Since that * is a value contained in an attribute- how do I selectively select only the asterisk part in the value attribute to make it red.

Comment: @Prabhas : I don't think it is possible in pure CSS

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays you can do this:

```
<input type="email"
       name="email"
       placeholder="Your Email"
       id="newsletter-subscribe-email-field">
```

Then style it like:

```
#newsletter-subscribe-email-field::placeholder,
#newsletter-subscribe-email-field::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#newsletter-subscribe-email-field:-ms-input-placeholder,
#newsletter-subscribe-email-field::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:#5472e8;
}
```

[::placeholder CSS pseudo-element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder)

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing this will suffice:

```
input[value] {
}
```

You can also prepend the selector with a PARENT id / class name to ensure it's unique for each form if need be.

http://jsfiddle.net/samuidavid/vz9qxsfw/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this ::

```
text.inpField {
       font-size: 10px;
       color: red;
    }
```